# Why viewWillTransition not triggering in landscape mode for the iPad in Split View but working fine for portrait mode?

Tags: swift, xcode, ipad, size-classes

To make it more clear I have created a demo app with only 2 ViewControllers. The issue only occurs on `iPad` on which I have kept all orientations enabled which are already enabled by default. So if I present a `UIViewController` as `FormSheet` on iPad, the `viewWillTransition` method is not triggering sometimes when iPad is in landscape mode. I tested it both in simulator as well as on the physical device. Firstly I thought it might be due to my code but in this demo it was clear, if I try to print a statement in `viewWillTransition` method in my `ViewController`, it will be printed every time no matter which orientation you are in. However, when I present a `FormSheet`, it will work for every orientation if iPad is in `Portrait` mode but if you switch to landscape mode, and try to change app size in `Split View`, sometimes the statement is not printed. It also happens if you have 2 apps opened in Split Mode with equal ratio and you switch your app to slideOver. So im confused why `viewWillTranstion` working fine for `portrait mode` but sometimes will not trigger for `landscape mode`?

This is my code in `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        
    }

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        }
        else {
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        }
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

And this is code for `SecondViewController`:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("Transition Detected")
        }
    }

}
```

Here is a video in which you can see the statement is only getting printed in portrait mode: https://youtu.be/iz5iOzOtGCg

It gets printed in landscape mode too but I have included the part ion which `viewWillTransition` is not triggering.

In `Portrait mode`, no matter what you do, rotate, change to Split View or drag size of app in Split View, or switch app to slipover, `Transition Detected` is printed. However in landscape mode, it will not print if you are in Split View and drag to make app small.

This behaviour is so confusing. Any idea how to detect all the transitions in landscape mode too?

Comment: It's not being called because the view is not actually changing size.

Comment: I can understand the presented viewController size is not changing in Split View but if I change from Split View(with 2 apps opened in equal ratio) to slideover, even then it's still not being triggered. view has definitely changed size then. Also when I switch back from slipover to Split View with 2 apps in equal ratio, it is triggered. So shouldn't it trigger in first case too? From 50% app size to slideover, it does not trigger, but back to 50% app size, it triggers.

Comment: @TylerP Actually all I want to do is keep aspect ratio of images in collectionView when I switch between layouts. And what is happening is when im switching from Split View to slideover, the image in cell is wider than slideover because im using width of view to calculate size of cell and invalidating layout in viewWillTransition method. It works for every situation except switching between slideover and Split View or small app size in Split View. Totally works fine for portrait mode